# Does using USB drives with identical World Wide Name (WWN) risk data loss?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, raid, zfs

I bought two m.2 SSD enclosures with identical [World Wide Name (WWN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name). (I didn't know such was possible.)

Will this cause data corruption if I use them on the same Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.02) server? If I use them in a ZFS RAID system, will Linux get them confused and write to one when it thinks it is writing to the other?

I've read there is risk of identifying them as a single multipath device, but I can't tell whether that applies if they're directly connected to USB ports on the computer, rather than on a USB hub.

I'm aware that I cannot attach them to the pool using `/dev/disk/by-id/`.  I'll just to attach them using the partition ID via `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.

So will two USB drives with the same WWN lead to data corruption with Ubuntu 20.04.02 if they're  attached to motherboard USB ports?

Comment: I’d consider WWNs on consumer-grade equipment useless.